# C++ tool to generate random XML files from XML Schema?

Tags: c++, xml, xsd

I think there should be a tool to do so ? is anyone here aware of any ?

I saw other posts related to this but found none for C++, I am aware that I can do that with JAVA and C#.

Comment: Why does the tool need to be written in C++?

Comment: Probably for integration with C++ unit tests... though I would guess that a C interface over a Java or C# component would work too in this case.

Comment: what is the name of the libraries allowing you to do that in java/C# ? that might be a good starting point for googling something like "name_of_library equivalent C++"

Comment: I wanted tweak-able options so the generic file generator would not work well, so I had to create the code-binding and generating the specific document now, Thanks a lot guys.

I need to know the values of some elements and I need to be able to configure some parts so that my tests (depending on those value-structures) do not fail. 

I tried Microsoft code generator, works well but generates real crap values and also does not supports patterns for string formats (need to create datetime, etc.) and have no control over it. changing that code would take more time than the concrete solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use XML Spy or oXygen, you can generate sample XML files based on a schema. Both tools accept commandline options and can be run in batch mode so that'll probably fit in your unit tests, if that's what you're after. Wrap your own C++ code around it and you're in business.

If you need quality XML, with tons of tweakable options, you might want to check out http://www.code-generator.com/XML-Sample-Generator.aspx. No C++ here, just a tool that works, and rises beyond the default "lorem ipsum..." output.

HTH,
~Rob